# Il m'aide et mon ami / Il (nous) aide(,) moi et mon ami

Tags: pronoms, syntaxe, coordination

Si on a des objets directs coordonnés, quelle est la bonne construction (ou la plus naturelle)? Par exemple:

1. Il m'aide et mon ami.
2. Il aide moi et mon ami.
3. Il nous aide, moi et mon ami.

Pour moi, la disclocation de *m'* et *mon ami* dans (1) est bizarre, tandis que l'usage de *moi* dans (2) au lieu de *m'* me semble dissonant. Peut-être qu'il faut (3) puisqu'on peut dire que *moi* dans (3) est plutôt un pronom disjoint qu'un pronom d'objet direct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il faut effectivement dire (3) *il nous aide, moi et mon ami* (ou plutôt *mon ami et moi*, qui est considéré comme plus poli).

Les deux premières constructions ne sont pas correctes.

Attention, on pourrait dire *il m'aide et mon ami aussi*, mais cela signifie que je reçois également de l'aide de mon ami.

Answer (score 2):

Par courtoisie je mettrais

*Il nous aide, mon ami et moi.*

Et si j'avais voulu insister sur le fait que l'aide est adressée à deux personnes, je mettrais

*Il nous aide tous les deux, mon ami et moi.*

ou

*Il nous aide, aussi bien mon ami que moi.*